# 403 Forbidden Error When Google Sign in API Redirect on Live Server

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, google-signin, http-status-code-403

I implemented Google SignIn API in my website, It works fine on LocalHost, but when i uploaded it on the Live Server, It gives Error 403 "Forbidden" after the user enter credentials and the google redirects the user to my website.
I tried following different articles online, but no luck so far.
Note: My Google App is already verified by Google.

[image: Screenshot error on live server after redirection]

[image: Screenshot when change redirect from local to live]

Comment: I edited the .htaccess file;
But now it redirects to index.php